# Can you set style in d3 via something like foo.style({color:blah, background:blah})?

Tags: d3.js

I am going to set various css styles on an svg element, and was thinking I could do something like

```
d3.selectAll(".whatever")
   .style(function(d) { return {"color":getColor(d), "background":getBackground(d)}});
```

Now, this doesn't work, but I'm wondering if I can do something similar to centralize setting overall style properties rather than set style properties individually.

Note: as Ray suggested, you can do something like this (I'm assuming you've already got data attached to the nodes):

```
d3.selectAll(".whatever")
  .attr("style",function(d) {
     return cssStyleStringYouWantToUse(d);
  });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Only works on D3 v3**:
To quote [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#style):

> If you want to set several style properties at once, use an object literal like so:
>
> selection.style({'stroke': 'black', 'stroke-width': 2})

This isn't possible with functions though, so in your case you still have to use the "long form".

Comment: Currently in v4, this requires an import and the function name changed to the plural form, eg: `selection.styles({})`. See [d3-selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi#d3-selection-multi)

Answer (score 6):

You can specify a separate function for each style name in the style literal, like so:

```
d3.selectAll(".whatever").style({
    color: function(d) { return getColor(d); },
    background: function(d) { return getBackground(d); }
});
```

Comment: thx Ray - yes, I know that.  The issue here is that I am exploring using potentially lots of style properties, and I was wanting to centralize it in a single function that takes the relevant data object and creates the object of styles - not a big deal, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: This is somewhat of a hack, but you could do: ```selection.attr('style', function(d) {return ...;});```

Comment: that's an interesting idea! and not sure why it wouldn't work!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way of applying multiple css (static or dynamic) in d3 is to set `style` as many times as you need it. For example:

`d3.selectAll('whatever')
    .style('color', 'green')
    .style('height', (d) => d + 'px');`